# Setting dynamically distinct id attribute using javascript for input element

Tags: javascript, html

I am facing a problem in setting distinct ids for dynamically added input boxes in a table. 
The problem is:

I am inserting new rows when the user clicks on "Add new Row". Now I have to set distinct id for the input box. I have taken a static variable and increasing its value every time user clicks on add new row button. Then I am appending its value to id value lets say temp (i.e. ids will be `temp1`, `temp2` and so on). I have taken a variable xyz as
`var xyz = "temp" + i` (where i is the counter)
and now I have to assign `xyz` to the id using `setattribute`.
But as values in `setattribute` can only be literals, how can I use a variable in place of the value?

If you have any other methods, please let me know.

Comment: It can be a variable which holds a string as well.

Answer (score 3):

It can be a variable which holds a string as well.

```
var fooId = "foo";
for (var i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
    document.getElementsByTagName('div')[i].setAttribute('id', fooId + (i + 1));
}
```

​**[Live DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4NHsU/1)**

Answer (score 2):

`setAttribute` allows for variables to be used as the value parameter.

eg:

```
var ele = document.createElement('div')
var id = 'temp1'
ele.setAttribute('id', id)
```

would result in:

```
<div id="temp1"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

`element.setAttribute("id", xyz);` Where element is your input.

Answer (score 2):

First of all `setattribute` is an undefined property of an element because of case-sensitivity while `setAttribute`, of course, is available.

Second, you are not absolutely required to use `setAttribute` at all. You can simply modify the `id` property to achieve the very same effect:

```
var el = document.createElement('div'), // your element
    staticPart = 'myUniqId', // your static part of a unique id
    i = 0; // your uniqueness

el.id = staticPart + i; // assign unique id to the element
// el.setAttribute('id', staticPart + i); // does the same, but more verbose

// Let's check if it worked:
el.getAttribute('id'); // "myUniqId0"
el.id; // "myUniqId0"
```

Third, where did you see that

> values in setattribute can only be literals

The spec says that `setAttribute` accepts two parameters, `name` and `value` of type [DOMstring](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#DOMString). You can pass it any value you want. Mind that it will be converted to String:

```
el.id = {a: 'b'};
el.id; // "[object Object]"
```

See http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-F68F082 and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.setAttribute

Answer (score -1):

```
for(;i<7;i++)
          {document.getElementById("test").innerHTML +='<form  id="form'+f+++'" method="get"><input type="text" id="in'+i+++'" size="12%"><input type="text" id="in'+i+++'" size="12%" ><input type="text" id="in'+i+++'"size="12%"><input type="text" id="in'+i+++'"size="10%" ><input type="text" id="in'+i+++'"size="10%"><input type="text" id="in'+i+++'" size="10%"><input type="text" id="in'+i+++'"size="12%"></form>'      
          }
```