# Changing percentage element of css through javascript, using a variable

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to change a the width value of my div using javascript. 
Using:

```
document.getElementById("id").style.width = "25%";
```

works fine for string literals, but I want to set the value using a variable.

Comment: I believe this is the [same question as this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13339996/601179). Maybe I was wrong with understanding of your question, what have you tried and didn't work?

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying! Your solution would have worked great, but I needed to calculate a value and then append a string like "%" or "px". I don't quite know this ins and outs of javascript, and didn't know that you could convert from int to string just by appending a string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When concatenating strings and variables javascript will use their string representation, try the following:

```
var variable = 25;
document.getElementById("id").style.width = variable + "%";
```

Comment: just to be sure you can use variable.toString().

Comment: @OnurTOPAL. Just be sure to delete the comment, when you concat a variable with a string there is an implicit conversion to string. :)

Comment: @OnurTOPAL This behaviour is well defined. There is no need to explicitly call toString() - it would just be wasted keystrokes.

Comment: yes in this case it is not need but if you can check this url http://jsfiddle.net/S37vw/ I know y++ just convert it to int but that also means JS easily convert types. that s why I said to be sure.